# Is there any way to change default folder location in IAR workbench with RTE configurated?

Tags: embedded, iar

I use IAR workbench and here is the default structure when it's created

```
Root

____|10_SDK (all file related to SDK, RTE should be here)

____|20_BSW

____|30_App

____|40_Workspace (contain .eww)

________|Project_1 (contain .ewp)

________|RTE

____________|CMSIS_Driver

____________|Device
```

I want to change the location of RTE from 40_.../Project_1 to 10_SDK so the implementation will be separated with workspace folder.

```
Root

____|10_SDK (all file related to SDK, RTE should be here)

________|RTE

____________|CMSIS_Driver

____________|Device

____| 20_BSW

____|30_App

____| 40_Workspace (contain *. eww)

________|Project_1 (contain *. ewp, ...)
```

Anyone know how to change it? Thank you!

Comment: You might want to fix your attempt at representing folder structure now I have applied plain-text mark-up  - leading spaces will work, no need for `_____`